# How create ref to call a function of a functional composant?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, methods, ref

After upgrading react native 0.60.
I try to change all my class composent to a functional composant.
For my animation I like to use methods of a composant (I know its not really recommended but I prefer that than create a state variable and pass it as a props...).

For exemple here is my class composant:

```
class Child extends PureComponent {
  animateOpen = () => {

  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        {...}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

```
const PlayButton = ({ status, onPress }) => {
  const childRef = useRef(null);

  return (
    <View>
      <Button onPress={this.childRef.animateOpen} />
      <Child ref={childRef}/>
    </View >
  );
};
```

So in this exemple, How can I do to wrote Child composant as a functional composant ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Child component as a functional component:

```
const Child = () => {
  const animateOpen = () => {}

  return (
    <View>
      {...}
    </View>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `this.childRef.current.animateOpen`